# How to make a fixed header and make it adaptive

Tags: html, css

I have a main div containing two divs. One takes up 276px, the other takes up the rest of the space (flex: 1). The second div has a header that should scroll along with the page. The problem is that now it takes up 100% of the width of the entire site, but it should only take up the length of the second block. I was able to set the required width when I set the main div to a fixed width and the header to max-width: inherit. But the problem is that the header has become non-adaptive and does not shrink when the screen gets smaller. How can this be implemented so that it is adaptive?

```css
.parent-div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.child-div-1 {
  width: 276px;
}

.child-div-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient( 102deg, #ff6662 -0.12%, #3268f4 117.01%, #193fb2 138.81%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div-1"></div>
  <div class="child-div-2">
    <div class="fixed-header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have additional functionality where this header appears when scrolling when the banner is not visible:

```js
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
    const header = document.querySelector(".fixed-header");

    if (banner) {
      let isBannerVisible = banner.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= 0;

      if (isBannerVisible) {
        header.classList.remove("show");
      } else {
        header.classList.add("show");
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to modify your code as per your requirement. I hope this helps:

```js
 window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
      const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
      const header = document.querySelector(".fixed-header");

      if (banner) {
        let isBannerVisible = banner.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= 0;

        if (isBannerVisible) {
          header.classList.remove("show");
        } else {
          header.classList.add("show");
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .parent-div {
      display: flex;
      gap: 20px;
    }

    .child-div-1 {
      width: 276px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    .child-div-2 {
      flex: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    .fixed-header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: calc(100% - 320px - 20px);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 8px 16px;
      height: 56px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      background: linear-gradient(102deg, #ff6662 -0.12%, #3268f4 117.01%, #193fb2 138.81%);
      z-index: 1000;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    }

    .fixed-header.show {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .content {
      margin-top: 80px;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div-1"></div>
    <div class="child-div-2">
      <div class="fixed-header"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
        <p>Demo text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position: fixed` as this is related to the viewport not the parent.

Use `position: sticky` instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child-div-1 {
  width: 276px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.child-div-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient( 102deg, #ff6662 -0.12%, #3268f4 117.01%, #193fb2 138.81%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div-1"></div>
  <div class="child-div-2">
    <div class="fixed-header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use sticky because it takes up space.
My header should initially be invisible and appear when scrolling